# Apache2 SSL And Passenger Configuration Issue

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, httpd.conf, phusion-passenger

I have the following virtual hosts configuration blocks.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/TestApp/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/TestApp/public/>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/TestApp/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/TestApp/public/>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

I trying to serve a Rails App off Passenger on Apache.

The Problem:

The TestApp works fine with Apache and Passenger when not using SSL
When I use `https://`, I see the contents of `/var/www/html`

The path to TestApp is `/var/www/html/TestApp`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Apache conf file and make sure that there is no other SSL-enabled virtualhost is being added. If your using a stock Apache installation, most likely the SSL-enabled virtualhost that is causing the problem is within /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

-Tony

Comment: I did this (6 months back though). It works.